# AngularJS - does it matter where $event.stopPropagation() is called?

Tags: angularjs, events, stoppropagation

I wanted to stop propagation of events on ng-repeat to parent elements. My code was:

```
<li ng-repeat="node in nodes"><div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); myFunc(node);"></li>
```

After struggling for a while, I figured that changing the order in which the functions were called on ng-click fixed it. I just had to change it to:

```
<li ng-repeat="node in nodes"><div ng-click="myFunc(node); $event.stopPropagation();"></li>
```

Why does the order matter here? In fact, I would imagine that calling $event.stopPropagation() should happen before anything else, so that the event propagation is stopped before anything else is done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@event object is created inside the ng-click directive, and it is available to you to pass it on to your ng-click handler function: ng-click="myFunc(node):... "

ngClick directive (as well as all other event directives) creates $event variable which is available on same scope. This variable is a reference to JS event object and can be used to call stopPropagation()

The $event.stopPropagtion is passed to the ng-click function myFunc(node); 
Angularjs Directives call the functions in order.

Comment: I think OP is wondering why order of functions in ngClick matters.

Comment: Well I assume the answer to that is the functions are called in order in the angularjs directives and the $event.stopPropagation() is called from within the click even function myFunc(node). The $event.stopPropagation is passed to the click event.